# Selenium IDE is automatically getting rid off

Tags: selenium, browsers

I am using selenium-ide-2.4.0 api in Mozilla Firefox 16, when i close and use Firefox 2 and again restart my Firefox 16 i need to re-install my api and use it, Why is it happening so?

Comment: Are you on a machine at work, or your personal machine? Have you checked the options to see if there is an option to clear out add-ons upon each reload?

Comment: im n machine at work , the problem is when i open in firefox 16 its working but when i close and use firefox 2 and restart my firefox 16, we should re install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a specific solution as I haven't needed to conduct compatibility testing on Firefox 2 for quite some time. However, I have a couple of suggestions based on the information you give which may help yo solve the issue.

1. Try to use separate profiles with each version of Firefox, and have the "Profiles" folder located in two separate places for each browser version.
2. Another thing to try would be to change the default location of where the Selenium add-on installs to (eg. change where all add-ons install to.
3. Finally, check when the add-on is uninstalled. Close the FF16 browser and check if the add-on is still there If so, open FF2 and see if the add-on is still installed. If so, close FF2 and check, then open FF16 and check. By finding when the add-on is removed, you may be able to find the setting that is causing the removal.

Comment: i think this might help a litle